# Real-Analysis: Finding Limit Points of Sets

Tags: real-analysis

***The question is the following:*** 
[image]

***And this is my attempt at a solution:***

[image]

Is this correct? Just looking for some feedback on whether or not I missed anything.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: This looks like Tex, you can more or less copy/paste your solution here and it will format as usual

Comment: I think your answers look more or less correct. As a simplifying factor, you can show that a countable number of open balls form a countable basis for $\mathbb{R}$: $\mathbb{B}=\{(q-\frac{1}{n}, q+\frac{1}{n}) \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. btw this means that $\mathbb{Q}$ is **dense** in the reals.

Comment: for part A, you might also want to shortly state why these are the *only* limit points for the set.

Comment: As Andres already wrote: $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. That is, for every real number $x$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$ you find a rational number $q$ such that $|x - q| < \varepsilon$. Therefore, the set of limit points of $B$ is the interval $(0,1)$.